# How to make runnable Python program in Linux

Tags: python

I want to to know how to make runnable Python program in Linux. It will pack all library is necessary into 1 file to run on any Linux machine.

Thank for reading and looking forward to answering

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458250/94746

Answer (score -1):

Linux machines will all have Python 2.5 at least installed.

Start the file with a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x filename.py
```

Then you can run it with the command:

```
$./filename.py
```

Comment: That works only for single files. He/She needs to pack everything into one executable.

Comment: Then you run it and the interpreter complains `ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'`.